# Utilizar includes() em um filter()

Tags: javascript, node.js

A função abaixo está renderizando todos os nomes de usuários, eu preciso incluir nela uma forma de filtrar os usuários renderizados de acordo com o que for digitado em um input text, tentei usar o includes() mas não estou conseguindo, como poderia aplica-lo nessa função???

```
function renderFoundUsers() {
  let foundUsersHTML = `<div>`;

  foundUsers.filter((user) => {
    const { name } = user;

    const userHTML = `
    <div>
    <ul>
    <li>${name}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    `;
    foundUsersHTML += userHTML;
  });
  foundUsersHTML += `</div>`;

  tabfoundUsers.innerHTML = foundUsersHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `.filter` retorna uma nova array, filtrada. Para isso funcionar tens de retornar dentro da callback desse filter um valor Booleano (true ou false) para indicar ao `.filter` se deve incluir ou não essa entrada que está a ser iterada. Para isso podias passar um argumento à função com o texto a procurar, e dentro da função filtrar ou não, conforme esse texto a filtrar seja vazio ou não.

Sugiro fazeres isso assim:

```js
function renderFoundUsers(searchString) {
  const filteresUsers = searchString ? foundUsers.filter(({
    name
  }) => name.includes(searchString)) : foundUsers;

  const usersHTML = filteresUsers.map(({
    name
  }) => {
    return `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>${name}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    `;
  }).join('');

  tabfoundUsers.innerHTML = `<div>${usersHTML}</div>`;
}
```